# Creating an API to a third party wss?

Tags: websocket, serversocket, wss

I am trying to get the OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE prices from a Chart
this is the website in question : [Website](https://pocketoption.com/en/cabinet/demo-high-low/).

**and this is how the chart looks:**

[image]

**After inspecting the flow of communication I noticed it connects to a websocket server:**

[image]

**Initiating a socket connection to this link:** wss://api-in.pocketoption.com:8095/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

gives something like this:

[image]

but after the response it closes the connection, Looking at the response I can see there is an sid  but can't figure what to do with the sid?

Comment: Did you figure it out yet

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be careful as that screenshot may contain information about your session which you may not want to share, like the 42["auth" {session...] packet. :)

That 42[] message format looks to be the Socket.IO event message, which makes me think that they are using Socket.IO in the backend. Even though Socket.IO is built on web sockets, you're better off attempting to connect with a proper Socket.IO library. (Whether or not it's against the EULA, not sure).

I dare say the server would need to receive the correct auth message in order for the socket to remain open, or else it will simply remote close the socket, but if you recreate the client at your end, you could easily listen in for specific instrument data. It may even be running multiple sockets, one which may not need auth for that data.